# add catalog product in wishlist programmatically in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I have created a product with custom option and I have showed the detail of this product on a custom page. Now I want to add the product in wishlist with filled custom option by user.
If i have to just add the product in wishlist, I can simply use the following code.

```php
<a href="'.Mage::helper("wishlist")->getAddUrl($_product).'" class="link-cart">Add to Wishlist /a>
```

but i want to insert the product with custom option. For this i have use following code but it gives me error "Cannot specify wishlist"

```php
$wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');
$storeId  = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$model    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product = $model->load($data['productId']);
$params   = array(
    'product'  => $data['productId'],
    'qty'      => 1,
    'store_id' => $storeId,
    'options'  => array(
        'optionId'  => 'option value',
        'optionId2' => 'option value2',
    )
);
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($params);
$result = $wishlist->addNewItem($_product, $request);
```

Comment: I found the solution my self.I have to just change the first line  $wishlist=Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')  to $wishlist = Mage::helper('wishlist')->getWishlist();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change first line

`$wishlist=Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')`

to

```
$wishlist = Mage::helper('wishlist')->getWishlist();
```